# Error validating data: ValidationError(PersistentVolume.spec) with Helm

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I've some automation where I can deploy my containers in GitLab automatically to K8s.

Right now I'm trying more advanced stuff and starting to use PersistentVolumeClaim so I created the file for that (app-pvc.yml), then when I commit the code I got the following error:

```
Tiller (the Helm server-side component) has been upgraded to the current version.
$ helm upgrade --install --set app.name="${NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}" --set app.image="${IMAGE}" --set app.host="${URL_PRODUCTION}" --wait --force --debug ${NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} ./k8s-chart
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '43379'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:43379"

UPGRADE FAILED
Error: Upgrade --force successfully deleted the previous release, but encountered 1 error(s) and cannot continue: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(PersistentVolume.spec): unknown field "resources" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolumeSpec
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: Upgrade --force successfully deleted the previous release, but encountered 1 error(s) and cannot continue: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(PersistentVolume.spec): unknown field "resources" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolumeSpec
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I'm very sure the file is properly indented and the project https://gitlab.com/my-k8s-containers/k8s-links worked without any issue previous I added the PVC file. This one was the last successful commit: https://gitlab.com/my-k8s-containers/k8s-links/commit/c86f20b918f02d81b0e211c073af865857f8d4af

Actually if I execute the following over the k8s cluster, the pvc is created without any issue:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: links-volume-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
EOF
```

And the entire repository this is the only file who contains the word resources.

I've dealing with this issue a lot and I can't figure out the solution.

Comment: Did you have a PersistentVolume (not a claim, an actual volume) in a previous version of the Helm chart?  Helm can be frustratingly stateful; try `helm del --purge "${NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} "` and then retry your installation.

Comment: It worked but it's weird because if I do a helm list I can't see anything related with this chart. But I remembered the name so I did a helm del --purge ${NAME} and I tried again and it worked :D